# Show it that $\inf(A \cdot B) = \inf(A) \cdot \inf(B)$

Tags: calculus

Where $A,B \subset \mathbb{R} $ arbitrary not empty sets and lower bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

$A \cdot B = \{ a \cdot b: a \in A, b \in B\}$

I'm trying to find a counterexample to it. I took $A=\{-1\}, B=[0,1]$ but it doesn't work. Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Doesn't your example work? $\inf(A \cdot B) = -1$ but $\inf(A)=-1$ and $\inf(B)=0$.

Comment: so is my counter example correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me! Indeed even $B=\{0,1\}$ (or any set of nonnegative numbers other than $\{0\}$) would work with $A=\{-1\}$ as well.